# Can you reccomend a screen capture application with audio?

Tags: video, audio, screen-capture, video-capture, conferencing

I will soon be attending a web course.

Is there any application that can record the video and audio being outputted to my screen?

My goal is to record the class so I can watch it later.

Windows platforms preferred.

Comment: [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) works pretty well, and also can capture your desktop (if you enable it to work with DWM).

Answer (score 4):

[Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) is a great software for this, it is not free but there is a 30 day trial.

[Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) is not as polished, but an open source, and free software to use.

Comment: I tried Camstudio, I do not think it allows you to record audio.

Comment: @CT It does. Go into Options and check Record Audio from microphone or speakers depending on what you wish to capture.

Comment: I have used and also recommend Camtasia.  Very mature and full featured product.

Answer (score 0):

For long session recording, you could use [Camstudio](http://camstudio.org/) with H.264 or Xvid codec.

Answer (score -1):

You could try http://www.screentoaster.com/

(not used yet, but looks powerful, multi-platform, and is free)

Comment: Web site and twitter feed for ScreenToaster both appear to be abandoned.

Comment: And now it's gone - error 403 when opening the link...