# what's the best video recording tool

Tags: windows, video, software-rec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you reccomend a screen capture application with audio?](https://superuser.com/questions/156205/can-you-reccomend-a-screen-capture-application-with-audio)

I want to know which tool is best to create video (Operation on Windows) for demo purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Camtasia From [Techsmith](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia) is one good software that has lots of features. It's not free by the way but not much expensive either. If you don't want to spend money on software then you can use Camstudio which is open source and free software as explained [in this reply](https://superuser.com/questions/220031/whats-the-best-video-recording-tool/220032#220032).

Answer (score 3):

[CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) - simple and free.

[image]